# append element to array in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, append

I have a matrix 10x500 and I want to discard every row which contains in the first 100 elements a value above 6. First I am trying to make an array with all the indexes of the row to discard. Here my code

```
idx_discard_trials = [];

for i = 1:size(data_matrix,1)
    if any(data_matrix(i,1:100)>6)   
        idx_discard_trials = i;
    end
end
```

However, at the end of the loop I get just the last index, not a list. Does anybody know how to append elements to an array using a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you keep rewriting a single value, you need to append the values through `idx_discard_trials(end+1) = i`, for example.

You don't need a loop for this however, try the following:

`data_matrix(any(data_matrix(:,1:100) > 6, 2),:) = []`